# Alternative for host file modification in order to test site before moving to new server?

Tags: file, server, dns, local, host

Is there an other option or browser add-on or program for testing/setting up a website with correct domain on a new server.

For example when I deploy a new website on a new server I would like to test it with the actual domain BEFORE changing the DNS settings so when I DO change the DNS the website works without problems.

Right now I modify the local host files to point domains to the new server (so I can test locally) but this seems a bit outdated..

Just wondering if there's something smarter/quicker..

Thanks for thinking with me!

Comment: Just search for browser extensions that can modify request headers (there are many of them) and modify `Host` header

Comment: Hi Dusan, thanks for your comment! Seems like a great tip and tried some but didn't yet got the result I wanted.. As to run a website domain on through a different IP so I can test an installation an another server before going live.. Any suggestions or experience with this one? Thanks!!